# React Как получить доступ или изменить соседский (sibling) элемент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста как менять состояние соседского элемента. Вот на [простом примере](https://codesandbox.io/s/find-sibling-x3yek?file=/src/Item.js)

```html
import React from "react";

class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  open = () => {
    console.log("this", this);

    ///  this.siblings(".itemBlock").classList.add("active");  /// Почему это не срабатывает

    console.log("this.myRef.current", this.myRef.current);

    this.myRef.current.siblings(".itemBlock").classList.add("active"); ///Почему это не срабатывает ?
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="item">
        <div className="itemBlock"></div>
        <button className="btnClick" onClick={this.open} ref={this.myRef}>
          {" "}
          clickMe
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

Хочу понять, как по нажатию на кнопку добавить класс соседскому элементу `(".itemBlock")`, который находиться в одном и том же `item`
Я прочитал что для таких проблем вроде как необходимо использовать [рефы](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) , но что-то пока не пришло понимание, как с ними работать. Есть ли решение данной задачи для функциональных компонентов ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function component

```js
export const Item = () => {
    const [isBtnClicked, setIsBtnClicked] = useState(false)
    
    const setBtnClicked = () => {
        setIsBtnClicked(true)
    }
    
    const open = () => {
        setBtnClicked()
    }
    
    return (
        <div className='item'>
            <div className='itemBlock'></div>
            <button
                className={`btnClick ${isBtnClicked ? "someClass" : ''}`}
                onClick={open}
            >
                {' '}
                clickMe
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Class component

```js
class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isBtnClicked: false,
        };
    }

    setBtnClicked = () => {
        this.setState({
            isBtnClicked: true,
        });
    };

    open = () => {
        this.setBtnClicked();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='item'>
                <div className='itemBlock'></div>
                <button
                    className={`btnClick ${
                        this.state.isBtnClicked ? 'someClass' : ''
                    }`}
                    onClick={this.open}>
                    {' '}
                    clickMe
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

With refs

```js
export function App() {
  const btnRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    btnRef.current.classList.add("someClass");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="item">
      <div className="itemBlock"></div>
      <button className={`btnClick`} ref={btnRef}>
        {" "}
        clickMe
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Или как написал @Максим Воробьев, лучше для таких задач юзать `classnames` либу

Comment: Добавление класса соседу было дано как самый примитивный пример.... Есть ли в React возможность без проброса состояния от родителя потомкам работать с нодами соседей ?

Comment: С помощью рефоф, по другому нiкак.

Comment: Добавил еще пример с рефами

Answer (score 2):

Для таких задач используется библиотека classNames

```html
import React from "react";
import classNames from 'classnames';

class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    }
  }

  open = () => {
   this.setState({isOpen: true})
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="item">
        <div className={classNames("itemBlock", isOpen ? "itemBlockOpen" : "")}></div>
        <button className="btnClick" onClick={this.open}>
          {" "}
          clickMe
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

Answer (score 1):

В Реакте у вас есть такая штука, как состояние(state). При клике на кнопку вы можете изменять объект state, в котором можете положить ключ `isActive`

Пример:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     isActive: false
    }
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({
     isActive: true
    })
  };

  render() {
    const activeClassItem = this.state.isActive ? 'itemBlock_active' : '';
    return (
      <div className="item">
        <div className={`itemBlock ${activeClassItem}`}  />
        <button className="btnClick" onClick={this.handleOpen}>
          {" "}
          clickMe
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/find-sibling-forked-61g9u?file=/src/Item.js)

Upd: Поправил, чтобы не появлялся лишний класс `false`

Comment: Только если `activeClassItem === false` в className будет `false` вместо `itemBlock_active`